# teleop not functioning with erratic

Tags: ros, gazebo, erratic, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am currently working with erratic and was able to get the robot to spawn in Gazebo by launching the launch files provided from the ros website. http://www.ros.org/wiki/erratic_description

But, the package did not include teleop, which is required to move the robot. I downloaded the teleop, and ran

rosrun erratic_teleop erratic_teleop_key

The command runs, but I am not able to move the robot. I used rxgraph, and it seems that the teleop node is not affecting the robot because it is not connected to it.

How would you make it so that the teleop node affects the erratic robot?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36804/teleop-not-functioning-with-erratic/) by [Gen_Robotino](https://answers.ros.org/users/2585/gen_robotino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried to post a response but I'm not sure it worked. Just something simple that I found was an issue sometimes, when you're running gazebo the impulse is to have that window be in the foreground and more than likely the window with mouse focus (meaning, basically, it was the last window you've clicked). The terminal running the teleop program needs to be the window with focus to catch any keyboard events.

Hope that helps.

update:

Also I just noticed that when I updated some packages, gazebo is brought up with time paused. This can cause the teleop to appear like it's not working. If you click on play on the upper left of the gazebo window, things should starting working.

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0